# UIAutomation with ToolStripStatusLabel

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, accessibility, ui-automation

I have a WinForms app, and I can't seem to access the text of a `ToolStripStatusLabel` through UIAutomation. Microsoft [implies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744822(VS.85).aspx) that the support for `StatusStrip`s (and presumably items within them) is limited, but this seems like a basic enough use case that it should work.

The control shows up with `ControlType.Edit` in UISpy, and appears to just be read-only text box, however its value is always the same as its name, not its text.

The properties in UISpy are as follows:

```
AutomationElement
  General Accessibility
    AccessKey:  ""
    AcceleratorKey: ""
    IsKeyboardFocusable:    "False"
    LabeledBy:  "(null)"
    HelpText:   ""

  State
    IsEnabled:  "True"
    HasKeyboardFocus:   "False"

  Identification
    ClassName:  ""
    ControlType:    "ControlType.Edit"
    Culture:    "(null)"
    AutomationId:   "StatusBar.Pane0"
    LocalizedControlType:   "edit"
    Name:   "My Label"
    ProcessId:  "3972 (*****)"
    RuntimeId:  "42 134002 0"
    IsPassword: "False"
    IsControlElement:   "True"
    IsContentElement:   "True"

  Visibility
    BoundingRectangle:  "(9, 273, 79, 17)"
    ClickablePoint: "48,281"
    IsOffscreen:    "False"

ControlPatterns
  GridItem
    Row:    "0"
    Column: "0"
    RowSpan:    "1"
    ColumnSpan: "1"
    ContainingGrid: ""status bar" "statusStrip""

  Value
    Value:  "My Label"
    IsReadOnly: "True"
```

Basically, I'm hoping for some way to go `myLabel.Text = "something"` and be able to get that value out somehow through UIAutomation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `AccessibleName` property in addition to `.Text` on the `ToolStripStatusLabel` control. It works for me using White in a similar scenario:

`statusLabel.Text = statusLabel.AccessibleName = "New status value";`

Answer (score 0):

I've had to work around this by having two separate labels with different text, and showing and hiding the appropriate one. This is enough for my purposes (testing with White), but I'm very surprised that UIAutomation doesn't surface the text value - it basically means all text in status bars in WinForms applications is inaccessible to screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

I have never had a problem retrieving the text of a label similar to what you describe. In fact the `AutomationId` is even the same in my application. The fact that `ControlType` is shown as `ControlType.Edit` is misleading. e.g. the following will work

```
statusText = (string)automationElement.GetCurrentPropertyValue(ValuePattern.ValueProperty);
```

Where `automationElement` has been located using a Find method against `ControlType.Edit` with an `AutomationId` of `"StatusBar.Pane0"`.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I'll try this next week! Any idea why it might be being exposed as an edit control? This is fine for me, but it seems like it would be misleading to a screen reader.